Avalonia DataGrid isn't visible
I am trying to using an Avalonia DataGrid in my MVVM project.
here's what my axaml view file looks like:
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="using:BalanceBuddyDesktop.ViewModels"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="600" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="BalanceBuddyDesktop.Views.AddExpensePageView"
             x:DataType="vm:AddExpensePageViewModel">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:AddExpensePageViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Expenses}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Margin="20"
                  Background="Blue">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"  Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

and here is my view model file:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using BalanceBuddyDesktop.Models;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace BalanceBuddyDesktop.ViewModels
{
    public partial class AddExpensePageViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private Expense _newExpense = new Expense();

        [ObservableProperty]
        private List<ExpenseCategory> _categories = GlobalData.Instance.ExpenseCategories;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<Expense> _expenses = new ObservableCollection<Expense>(GlobalData.Instance.Expenses);

        public AddExpensePageViewModel()
        {

        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void AddExpense()
        {
            GlobalData.Instance.Expenses.Add(_newExpense);
            _expenses.Add(_newExpense);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_expenses));
            _newExpense = new Expense();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_newExpense));
        }
    }
}


I'm not getting any errors. I have installed Avalonia.Controls.DataGrid and the version matches up with the version of Avalonia that I've installed. The functionality of adding an expense in AddExpense() is correct. Yet nothing is rendered. Everything works fine if I just use a ListBox instead!

Never used the Avalonia DataGrid, but does it make sense to set AutoGenerateColumns="True" when you also manually declare <DataGrid.Columns>?

You may also want to use a Grid instead of a StackPanel as the top-level element in the UserControl's XAML.
